# Linked list, Class struct?

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

Can u build a struct with a class type data member?

I have a class file  and my goal is to build a linked lints of characters each with their own names and other attributes.

now to build the list i need a member that will hold the data and a node pointer
my question is could i build something like this. all this is being done in a class file and whenever i run it i get an error at the struct, BigHero doesn't name type.

help this noob XD

```
 #include <string>
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 #ifndef BIGHERO_H
 #define BIGHERO_H

struct Node{
    BigHero data;
    Node* Next;
    };

class BigHero
{
 public:

     BigHero();

     /* Parameterized constructor
      * Set private members to parameter values
      * NOTE:  level is initialized as the interger division of exp/100
      *        i.e. if exp = 250 -> level = 2       */
       BigHero(string newName, int newExp, int newStr, int newIntel, int            newDex);

        /* Accessors:  each accessor will return the value of the appropriate 
        private data member */
        string getName() const;
        int getExp() const;
        int getStr() const;
        int getInt() const;
        int getDex() const;
        int getLevel() const;

        /* Mutators:  each mutator will take one parameter and update the    

         appropriate private data member 
        * The domain for each mutator is listed below.  
        * The mutator should protect against invalid values.  
        * An Invalid entry should result in the original value remaining unchanged. */
         void setName( string newName );   // All strings are valid
         void setExp( int newExp );        // 0 <= newExp <= 9000
         void setStr( int newStr );        // 0 <= newStr <= 300
         void setInt( int newInt );        // 0 <= newInt <= 300
         void setDex( int newDex );        // 0 <= newDex <= 300
         void setLevel( int newLevel );    // 1 <= newLevel <= 100


         bool addExp( int amount );


         void levelUp();

        bool operator<( const BigHero& rhs ) const;
        bool operator>( const BigHero& rhs ) const;
        bool operator==( const BigHero& rhs ) const;


       friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const BigHero& rhs);

     /* Input should be in the format: "Name exp Str Intel Dex" 
     * Don't forget to update level value to be equal to the integer division of exp/100 */
       friend istream& operator>> (istream& is, BigHero& rhs);

     ~BigHero();

     private:
         string name;    // Hero's name
         int exp;        // Experience points (100 exp = 1 level)
         int level;      // Hero's level
         int Str;        // Hero's strength
         int Intel;      // Hero's intelligence
         int Dex;        // Hero's dexterity

         Node* head;
         Node* tail;


        };

        #endif // BIGHERO_H
```

Comment: #include <bighero.h> ?

Comment: this struct is in the class file

Comment: compiled class file?

Comment: I think you should follow a tutorial. I have a hard time seeing that SO will be any good for tutoring people into the complexities of C++

Comment: let me edit the post ... will post the whole class file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node` contains a `BigHero`, so to allocate a `Node`, `Node` needs to know the size of `BigHero` to be able to determine how much storage is required. That means `BigHero` must be fully defined, and it's size known, before `Node` can be defined.

```
class BigHero
{
     // Rest of BigHero omitted to save space
     Node* head;
     Node* tail;
};

struct Node{
    BigHero data;
    Node* Next;
};
```

## But...

`BigHero` needs to know that the concept of `Node` exists and will be defined elsewhere to be able to contain pointers to `Node`. This is solved with a forward definition of `Node`. So

```
struct Node;
class BigHero
{
     // Rest of BigHero omitted to save space
     Node* head;
     Node* tail;
};

struct Node{
    BigHero data;
    Node* Next;
};
```

Comment: @William _"u the man"_ What makes you sure that this is a male user? I cannot see any evidence from their profile.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that the C++ compiler hasn't seen the BigHero class yet when it gets to the struct definition, so it doesn't know what to do with it.

Forward-declare the BigHero class by putting this:

```
class BigHero;
```

Before the Node struct.

Comment: Wrong way around; he uses BigHero as a value in Node, but only uses Node as a pointer in BigHero.

Comment: Does that not mean he needs the forward-declaration of BigHero before Node is defined?

Comment: Means he needs to move the definition of `node` to after `BigHero` and forward define `Node` ahead of `BigHero`.